# Simple tikz picture, a line connecting nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to align the text a -- b -- c at the bottom and not at the top as it is now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[right=of a] (b) {b}; 
\node[right=of b] (c) {c}; 
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Moreover, I would like to know: Do I have to place the tikzpicture always inside a "figure" environment? Because, if I do not, then it appears aligned with the rest of the text and not as "a picture". 
Lastly, I would like to have small circles in the place of a, b, c in the tikzpicture above (and the names a,b,c above these circles), but when I do it, the connecting lines touch the circles, which I do not like. I would prefer the current format (where the line does not touch a, b and c but connects them) and have circles instead. How can I do it?

Since it is just a simple picture of a line connecting three points, I would like to keep the code as simple and basic as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you would need to always have a `tikzpicture` inside a `figure` environment? You don't. If it is a figure with a caption that should float, then use `figure`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your original code, to align the nodes at the bottom, you can set the appropriate anchors, by saying `right=of a.south east,anchor=south west`, instead of just `right=of a`. Depending on what you want, you might want to use the `base west` anchor instead of `south west`, but then you can use `base right=of` instead of `right=of`, as shown in the code below.

You do get problems with drawing the lines, as they appear to be drawn between the `east` and `west` anchors, and since these are at different vertical positions, the lines are tilted a bit. There are probably several methods for fixing that, the one shown below is like this:

```
\draw (a) -- (b.west |- a.east)
      (c.west |- a.west) -- (a.west -| b.east);
```

The construct `(<coord 1> |- <coord 2>)` is a coordinate specification (see section 13.3.1, *Intersections of perpendicular lines*, in the manual). It is the point that has the x-coordinate of `<coord 1>`, and the y-coordinate of `<coord 2>`. Think of `|-` as two lines, one going vertically from the first point, one horizontally from the second, and the coordinate is at the intersection of those. Similarly, with `-|` you get the y-coordinate of the first point, and the x-coordinate of the second.

Note further that if you do `\draw (a) -- (b) (c) -- (d);` then you will not get a line between `b` and `c`, because there is no `--` between the coordinates.

Finally, I show a method for having circles with letters above. If you don't require the vertical alignment at the baseline, you can remove the `[anchor=base,label distance=1mm]` from the `circ` style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
Aligning nodes at their bottom (left) or baseline (right):

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[right=of a.south east,anchor=south west] (b) {b}; 
\node[right=of b.south east,anchor=south west] (c) {y}; 
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[base right=of a] (b) {b}; 
\node[base right=of b] (c) {y}; 
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);  
\end{tikzpicture}

Tweaked to get horizontal lines:

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[right=of a.south east,anchor=south west] (b) {b}; 
\node[right=of b.south east,anchor=south west] (c) {y}; 
\draw (a) -- (b.west |- a.east)
      (c) -- (c.west -| b.east);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[base right=of a] (b) {b}; 
\node[base right=of b] (c) {y}; 
\draw (a) -- (b.west |- a.east)
      (c.west |- a.west) -- (a.west -| b.east);  
\end{tikzpicture}

With circles:

\begin{tikzpicture}[
   circ/.style={ % style for the nodes
     draw=blue!50,  % draw with given color
     circle,
     fill=blue!10, % fill color
     inner sep=0pt, % remove all padding in node
     minimum size=2mm, % set size
     outer sep=2pt, 
     label={[anchor=base,label distance=1mm]above:#1} % The #1 indicates that the style takes one argument, so use as circ={...}
    }]

\node [circ=a] (a) {}; 
\node [circ=b, right=of a] (b) {}; 
\node [circ=y, right=of b] (c) {}; 
\draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum -- `mid`

After glancing at the manual I realized that the `mid east`/`mid west` anchors can be used here along with `base right` for slightly shorter code, at least for the present case. The `mid` anchors are defined to be 0.5ex above the baseline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node(a) {a}; 
\node[base right=of a] (b) {b}; 
\node[base right=of b] (c) {y}; 
\draw (a.mid east) -- (b.mid west) (b.mid east) -- (c.mid west);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, I would like smaller circles and fill (ok, I just add ", fill" but how do I make them smaller?) And I also want to know in the initial code in my question (without the circles), how do I align a, b, c as they are here (at the bottom and not at the top)? Thank you

Comment: @JimmyR. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer! The only option that works for me, is the second (on the right I mean) under your line "tweaked to get horizontal lines" (and of course the one with the circles). So, I certainly produced the result that I was looking for in my text! One question: I do not get the code: \draw (a) -- (b.west |- a.east)  (c.west |- a.west) -- (a.west -| b.east); Can you please explain it? Which command establishes the connecting line between b and c for example?

Comment: @JimmyR. Clearer now?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit clearer, not totally, but I can work it out from here on by myself (I will check probably the manual if necessary)! I am only a bit disappointed that such a simple problem did not have a straightforward simple solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JimmyR. There might be better solutions, that I'm not aware of. I did just add one other option, using a different anchor, but it does have its drawbacks.

Comment: It is a great answer with a lot of work and effort from you! I like the addition too (the previous things worked already, but since the addition (the mid option I mean) works fine and the code is more transparent, I am going to use this instead! Before my question, I was thinking that there would be an answer of the kind "add some short of [align=bottom]" and you are done. That is what I meant with "not straightforward answer", but apparently there is no such option. Everything you posted is very versatile and works exactly fine! So, thanks again!